# Distribution of magnitude squared for complex Gaussian

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

$\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}$
If we have a random complex variable $h_l$, with

$\Re[h_l]\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_l^2/2)$

and

$\Im[h_l]\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_l^2/2)$

and $\Pr(\Re[h_l] \cap \Im[h_l])=\Pr(\Re[h_l])\times \Pr(\Im[h_l])$

then how do you prove the distribution of $|h_l|^2$, i.e. $\Pr(|h_l|^2=x)$? I know it is exponential.

My attempt:

$\int_{a=0}^1 \Pr(\Re[h_l]^2=x-a)\Pr(\Im[h_l]^2=a)da$

$=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\sigma_l^2}}e^{-\frac{\sqrt{x-a}+\sqrt{a}}{\sigma_l^2}}da$

But I am having trouble with using substitution for that integral since substituting

$g=-\frac{\sqrt{x-a}+\sqrt{a}}{\sigma_l^2}$

Leads to two solutions for a in terms of $g$ so I can't substitute $da$ with $dg$ as $\sqrt{.}$ is not a function (one to many mapping).

Comment: Yes, question has been edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. normal variables with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$. Then:
$$\mathbb{P}[X^2+Y^2\leq d^2] =\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\int_{x^2+y^2\leq d^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,dx\,dy, $$
so, switching to polar coordinates:
$$\mathbb{P}[X^2+Y^2\leq d^2]=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\int_{0}^{d}\rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,d\rho=1-e^{-\frac{d^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
giving that the distribution of $X^2+Y^2$ is exponential as wanted.

Comment: And then we differentiate the cumulative distribution to get the actual distribution, great!